# C# query operation

Tags: c#

I have a class for Connect to db and execute the query

```
public class dbConnect
{
    public MySqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
    public MySqlCommand cmd;
```

....

```
public void Connetti()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                Connection.Open();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Errore " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

How is possible return the MySqlCommand cmd ?

```
public void SetQuery(string sSQL)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSQL, Connection);
        //return cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }

}
```

It would be useful to have the MySqlCommand instance return, for use in datatable.Load => dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        conn.Connetti();

        //MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tb_navi Order By NOMENAVE", conn.Connection);                        conn.SetQuery("SELECT * FROM tb_navi Order By NOMENAVE");

        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        //dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        dt.Load(conn.cmd);   //now cmd is null
        dtGrid.DataContext = dt; 

    }
```

Comment: you could possibly return an IEnumerable of results and exploit the yield statement to iterate over the read calls to the reader

Answer (score 3):

Return a populated `DataTable` from your method:

```
public DataTable SetQuery(string sSQL)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sSQL, Connection))
    {
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public DataTable GetTableData(string StrSQL)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = null;
        MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = null;
        try
        {


                mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(StrSQL, Connection);                    
                mySqlDataReader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                dataTable.TableName = "mydata";
                dataTable.Load(mySqlDataReader);                    

        }
        finally
        {
            if (mySqlDataReader != null)
            {
                if (!mySqlDataReader.IsClosed)
                {
                    mySqlDataReader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
```